# How to use data when submit button is clicked for next sql query

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysqli

I am trying to create an html form where i have a dropdown menu populated with data from stations table. I am able to select a station and then i want to use this station name when a button is clicked to display a table with related data. But i don't understand how i can use selected station to create another query when submit button is clicked.  Below is my code:

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Choose a station:</label>
            <select name="owner">
                <?php 
                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM stations");
                while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                    ?>
                    <option value="owner1"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

i think **onclick** must be used but i don't understand what would be posted that i can use for new sql query.

Answer (score 0):

When you click submit button browser send form via POST method to the same page and reload it. So you can capture the value selected in the form with this PHP code:

```
If (isset($_POST['owner'])) {
// mysqli query where the selected value is $_POST['owner']
}
```

Comment: yes but it is not showing any data. query i am using is ```SELECT name, available_spots FROM stations WHERE name = '".$_POST['owner']."' ```

Comment: The correct way is ...     WHERE name = '$_POST[owner]'